# CPP graphics.h library in devc++

Tags: c++, bgi

```
int driver=DETECT,mode;
initgraph(&driver,&mode,"");
void far *img;
getimage(200,200,500,400,img);
putimage(200,200,img,COPY_PUT);
getch();
closegraph();
```

I have question. When I run the above code it show the BGI Windows and then and immediately it disappeared why?

Comment: Getting BGI, a thirty-some year old graphics library, working on modern computers can be pain. There are updates and ports of this library, [some of them quite recent and credible](https://github.com/genpfault/sdl-bgi), but you have to be careful. If the course you're taking provided a bgi library and specified a tool chain, use them exactly. You don't want to write something that works perfectly on your PC and fails miserably on the marker's PC. If you're doing this for your own reasons, use what you want.

Comment: Dear! Every function of graphics.h run successfully, but this one irritated me too a lot. Now I have questions is it essential for learning cpp? if it is not in our course.

Comment: If it disappeared without you having to provide a character to `getchar`, it did not run successfully. Probably because no storage has been allocated for `img` before calling `getimage`. Note: I have not used BGI in (literally) decades and can't help much here. but a websearch for *bgi getimage* should find some documentation and possibly usage examples.

Comment: Is BGI essential? Not really. It is a graphics API designed using 1980's C programming idioms to run on the awesomely limited graphics devices of the time. There are much better and more useful graphics tools to learn and use today. I normally direct people to the graphics libraries in [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org/) or [SFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org/) if they are beginners who wish to learn graphics.

Comment: @WajahatKhan BGI has nothing to do with  C++. Even back in the days we usually rather use VGA 320x200x256c and  direct VRAM memory access instead of BGI... If you want graphics then you need to decide what for  ... OpenGL/DirecX are good for vector based graphics GDI is good for simple charts and raster stuff... the other win libs usually just encapsulate one of those 3 ...